# Django migrate gives import error for expatreader

Tags: django, django-south, importerror, migrate

I am trying to create a migration, but i keep receiving this error:

```
(workon_development)[hmaster@teacher work]# _django migrate tut_app_
Running migrations for tut_app_:
  - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
  > tut_app_:0001_initial
  - Loading initial data for tut_app_.
ImportError: No module named expatreader
```

If I do syncdb:

```
(workon_development)[hmaster@teacher work]# _django syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
ImportError: No module named expatreader
```

Any hints?

Comment: well it seems somewhere you're trying to import expatreader (is this a name you gave for something you're trying to create?) in either your settings.py (installed apps), urls.py, views.py etc...

Comment: Actually no. I just created a new Django project, app, within a virtualenv.
But I created a new virtualenv, just now, and everything works.
I must admit that I have played alot with the "old" virtualenv, and particulary with XML extensions, and some SOAP libraries.
It may be that something got wrecked, but I am trying to understand what/where...

I will try to dive more into it, and mitigate the issue somehow.
I'll be back with new comments ...

Thank you.

Comment: glad you figured it out.